# React: formik form, how to use state after submit inside a callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik

I am using `formik` plugin in `reactjs` and I want to `useState` variables after form submit.

Both `this` and `setState` are undefined and I can't achieve it.
Can anybody please help me to get this done?

See screenshot (below) [image]

Comment: You are going to need to provide at least `some` code as an example. There are way too many ways to do what you are asking.

Comment: Jason it is added , see image in question

Comment: Do you have a constructor in your class that sets the initial state?

Comment: No
let me know how can I set that

Comment: Sorry but I am new to reactjs so that is why I not know these dept details

Comment: actually I can do that in other places but not inside formik plugin submit function

Comment: you have to place it at the top of the class definition.

Comment: Did you bind the `LoginApp` function to that component? You might to do that for `this` to be defined.

Comment: yes now I used and it is working. you saved my hours @MwamiTovi
thanks sir
please post your answer so that I can mark it correct

Comment: For what it's worth .. next time please add actual code instead of a picture so people can see everything you are doing instead of having to guess.

Comment: sure @JasonI will follow. thanks for advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `JavaScript`, class methods are not bound by default.
If you forget to bind `this.LoginApp` and pass it to `onSubmit`, `this` will be `undefined` when the function is actually called (as you already noted).

> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript.

Generally, if you refer to a method without `()` after it, such as `onSubmit={this.LoginApp}`, you should bind that method. And to avoid performance problems, it's generally recommended to bind in the constructor or using the class fields syntax. [Here's a good read from the react team](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

```js
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {...};

  // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
  this.LoginApp = this.LoginApp.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: thanks
it fixed my issue and now state is available